# Word for gesture of pinching cheeks

Tags: expressions, gestures

Is there a word / expression for the gesture of pinching someone's cheeks to show affection. It is often done to kids although people with dimples are also a frequent target for this kind of gesture.

Comment: It is quite literally "pinching [his/her/their] cheeks".